# Create a view that displays a related term users

Tags: 7, views, users

- I created a "Group" vocabulary with the terms "Company 1", "Company 2", ...
- I created a field on the account setting.
- I linked my user account "Company 1" and 4 other users.
- I created a view that displays a list of users.

How to display only users associated with the same duration as the currently logged in user?

thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'views_groupe';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'Groupe';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Groupe';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'uid' => 'uid',
  'field_code_groupe' => 'field_code_groupe',
  'field_groupe' => 'field_groupe',
  'name' => 'name',
  'mail' => 'mail',
  'ops' => 'ops',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'uid' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_code_groupe' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_groupe' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'mail' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'ops' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: User: Groupe */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_groupe']['id'] = 'field_groupe';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_groupe']['table'] = 'field_data_field_groupe';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_groupe']['field'] = 'field_groupe';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_groupe']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term_reference_plain';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Nom d\'utilisateur';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_user'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
/* Contextual filter: User: Groupe (field_groupe) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['id'] = 'field_groupe_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_groupe';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['field'] = 'field_groupe_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['exception']['title'] = 'Tout';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_groupe_tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'groupe';
$translatables['views_groupe'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Groupe'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Nom d\'utilisateur'),
  t('Tout'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Views query alter should help.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == "views_groupe") { 
  global $user; 
  $user_data = user_load($user->uid);
  if (isset($user_data->field_groupe)) {
    $company_name = $user_data->field_groupe['und']['0']['tid'];
    $query->add_table('field_data_field_groupe');
    $query->add_where(0, 'field_data_field_groupe.field_groupe_tid', $company_name, '=');
  } 
 }
}
```

Remove all the contextual filters set, only have the filter you set under filter criteria.

Comment: Your method works for nodes associated with the terms, but not for user related terms. This shows no result. Even putting a fixed value, it displays nothing.

Comment: Hey Mathieu, I gave a try as well, but I'm able to pull the values.I created a view of the type user and had the company_field created in the user entity as a base field. Simply gave User:company_name in the contextual filters with the above criteria and was able to pull the result, let me know are we on the same page

Comment: I've updated the question, but it still does not work.

Comment: -Ok, I found the problem with the previous solution as my term id and user id were same and that they populated the result. I have given a simple query alter which should serve the purpose, Hope it helps :).

Comment: thank you, you have to put it in the template.php my theme?

Comment: In a module file, this should help you get started [function hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x)

Comment: Thank you for your help. the way to my view is "user/%/groupe". Is it possible to tid of the term associated with the user in the way of the view. This would avoid making a custom module.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem. I will use the "Group" module or "Organic Group". But I do not know the which to choose. A group must be able to view the orders of its members. An idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using contextual filters and relations.

1. Add the contextual filter "User: uid".
2. Under "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" select "Provide default value" -> "User id from logged in user".
3. Add a required relationship: "Taxonomyterm:
   Content with term."
4. Finally, on top of your view field preferences select your added relationship.